# Freezes at splashscreen after apt-get upgrade

Tags: boot, upgrade, apt, package-management, freeze

Hello dear askubuntu community!
A few weeks ago i switched from Vista to Ubuntu and I'm very happy with that. But yesterday i upgraded my packages (for the first time) with "sudo apt-get upgrade" and now everytime i try to start my computer it freezes at " *Stopping userspace Bootsplash  [OK]"

I should mention that after installing Ubuntu for the first time, I've had a problem with my graphics card driver (I got a AMD Radeon HD6570). ubuntu wasn't displayed properly so i downloaded the driver from the AMD Website and installed it manually. It worked fine since then.

I'd be glad if anyone could help me out with that.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).